# My 'decrypt' code doesn't work correctly

Tags: java

I am not sure but I think my problem is that my function doesn't compare the char´s right. Am I using the Switch also right?

my input x is a String and when x = "aaaaa" it returns "aaaaa" instead of "zzzzz".

```
String c = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            char getChar = x.charAt(i);

            switch (getChar) {
                case 1: (getChar) = 'a';
                        c += "z";
                        break;
                case 2: (getChar) = 'b';
                        c += "y";
                        break;
                case 3: (getChar) = 'c';
                        c += "x";
                        break;
                case 4: (getChar) = 'd';
                        c += "w";
                        break;
                case 5: (getChar) = 'e';
                        c += "v";
                        break;
                case 6: (getChar) = 'f';
                        c += "u";
                        break;
                case 7: (getChar) = 'g';
                        c += "t";
                        break;
                case 8: (getChar) = 'h';
                        c += "s";
                        break;
                case 9: (getChar) = 'i';
                        c += "r";
                        break;
                case 10:(getChar) = 'j';
                        c += "q";
                        break;
                case 11:(getChar) = 'k';
                        c+= "p";
                        break;
                case 12:(getChar) = 'l';
                        c += "o";
                        break;
                case 13:(getChar) = 'm';
                        c += "n";
                        break;
                default :
                        c += x.charAt(i);
            }
        }

    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: You should use `case 'a'`.. instead. The decimal value of `'a'` is not 0. Also use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of `+`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun why is it better to use StringBuilder instead of what i do?

Comment: See [this link](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/strings.html) for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
switch (getChar)//<--You are passing charcter in switch case 
//but checking for 1,2 int as case 1,2...
```

What you need to change is your `case`

as in `switch` you will be passing characters like `a,b,c...`

```
switch(getchar)
{
 case 'a':
  //yourwork
  break;
 //do this for all letters
}
```

---

*NOTE*

*Moreover for concacting `String` you  should use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) (As Maroun Maroun) has already suggested and use `stringBuilder.append('char')` method to add your character to String builder directly no need to use `String` (i.e "a","b" etc.).*

Comment: why is it better to use StringBuilder instead of what i do?

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` statement is not the best option if all cases are treated in almost exactly the same way and can be easily converted into a single calculation. You can replace the entire switch statement with this `if`/`else` block:

```
if (getChar >= 'a' && getChar <= 'm') {
    char newChar = (char) ('z' - (getChar - 'a'));
    c += newChar;
} else {
    c += getChar;
}
```

NOTE: @TAsk and @MarounMaroun are right in advising you to use StringBuilder to build up your result.